# How to deploy multiple Android/IOS app builds with same codebase on flutterflow?

Tags: flutter

I'm starting a new project that will sell "white label" apps, all with the same funcionality, just changing some resources and colors.
There is any way to build an app in flutterflow and have multiple builds, each one with a config file for that specific build
The intention is everytime I update the app code and funcionality, all my clients will receive the updated version, each one with their custom name/skin.
Thanks

I didnt find any way to do this in flutterflow, the apps have a single output for each platform and cloned projects stay obsolete when I update the main app.

Comment: What about writing a custom shell script for that

Comment: You can pass, env vars while doing a `flutter build` with `--dart-define` parameter and read them inside the flutter with `String.fromEnvironment`

Comment: With this vars you can control the behaviour of app and than make custom sgell scripts like `fflutter build apk --dart-define=USER=username1`